# Search Array and find Key Value

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I have a array

```
array(153) { [0]=> string(47) "colg - colgate palmolive (pakistan) ltd. " [1]=> string(47) "gatm - gul ahmed textile mills ltd. " [2]=> string(47) "atlh - atlas honda limited " [3]=> string(33) "ffbl - fauji fertilizer bin qasim" [4]=> string(16) " - general news" [5]=> string(49) "searl - the searl company ltd. " [6]=> string(47) "jdws - j. d. w. sugar mills ltd. " [7]=> string(47) "aabs - al- abbas sugar mills limited. " [8]=> string(37) "hmb - habib metropolitan bank limited" [9]=> string(37) "hmb - habib metropolitan bank limited" [10]=> string(23) "ogdc - oil & gas dev.co" [11]=> string(39) "ffc - fauji fertilizer company limited." [12]=> string(46) "bop - bank of punjab limited. " [13]=> string(46) "bop - bank of punjab limited. " [14]=> string(30) "luck - lucky cement limited " [15]=> string(47) "natf - national foods limited. " [16]=> string(46) "pol - pakistan oilfields ltd. " [17]=> string(47) "psmc - pak suzuki motor co. ltd. " [18]=> string(35) "nbp - national bank of pakistan ltd" [19]=> string(27) "ncpl - nishat chunian power" [20]=> string(25) "tgl - tariq glass limited" [21]=> string(47) "bahl - bank al-habib limited " [22]=> string(33) "ffbl - fauji fertilizer bin qasim" [23]=> string(136) " kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30 " [24]=> string(9) "26,730.82" [25]=> string(5) "60.22" [26]=> string(18) "volume: 96,370,040" [27]=> string(9) "19,289.00" [28]=> string(6) "-18.68" [29]=> string(18) "volume: 43,582,400" [30]=> string(9) "43,968.61" [31]=> string(6) "-61.00" [32]=> string(18) "volume: 27,252,400" [33]=> string(3) "anl" [34]=> string(4) "9.73" [35]=> string(4) "0.58" [36]=> string(10) "23,192,000" [37]=> string(4) "jscl" [38]=> string(5) "12.53" [39]=> string(4) "1.00" [40]=> string(10) "20,936,000" [41]=> string(4) "jsil" [42]=> string(5) "13.75" [43]=> string(4) "0.35" [44]=> string(10) "10,966,500" [45]=> string(5) "power" [46]=> string(4) "8.00" [47]=> string(4) "0.71" [48]=> string(9) "7,161,000" [49]=> string(4) "piaa" [50]=> string(4) "9.80" [51]=> string(4) "0.16" [52]=> string(9) "6,978,500" [53]=> string(4) "lpcl" [54]=> string(5) "10.40" [55]=> string(5) "-0.04" [56]=> string(9) "5,988,500" [57]=> string(3) "bop" [58]=> string(5) "11.34" [59]=> string(4) "0.11" [60]=> string(9) "5,785,000" [61]=> string(4) "byco" [62]=> string(4) "9.39" [63]=> string(4) "0.47" [64]=> string(9) "4,972,000" [65]=> string(5) "kasbb" [66]=> string(4) "2.39" [67]=> string(4) "0.34" [68]=> string(9) "4,910,500" [69]=> string(3) "spl" [70]=> string(5) "19.78" [71]=> string(4) "0.65" [72]=> string(9) "4,600,000" [73]=> string(6) "nestle" [74]=> string(9) "11,989.16" [75]=> string(6) "570.91" [76]=> string(5) "2,100" [77]=> string(4) "iltm" [78]=> string(8) "1,564.92" [79]=> string(5) "74.52" [80]=> string(3) "500" [81]=> string(5) "mureb" [82]=> string(6) "913.18" [83]=> string(5) "43.48" [84]=> string(6) "57,500" [85]=> string(5) "wyeth" [86]=> string(8) "4,600.00" [87]=> string(5) "33.50" [88]=> string(3) "600" [89]=> string(4) "colg" [90]=> string(8) "1,700.00" [91]=> string(5) "15.50" [92]=> string(3) "140" [93]=> string(4) "hino" [94]=> string(6) "292.87" [95]=> string(5) "13.94" [96]=> string(3) "400" [97]=> string(3) "ici" [98]=> string(6) "323.00" [99]=> string(5) "11.55" [100]=> string(7) "103,500" [101]=> string(4) "pict" [102]=> string(6) "270.98" [103]=> string(4) "9.88" [104]=> string(6) "29,200" [105]=> string(4) "pkgs" [106]=> string(6) "309.00" [107]=> string(4) "9.04" [108]=> string(6) "37,800" [109]=> string(4) "jdmt" [110]=> string(6) "168.49" [111]=> string(4) "8.02" [112]=> string(5) "3,500" [113]=> string(4) "upfl" [114]=> string(8) "9,100.00" [115]=> string(6) "-90.00" [116]=> string(3) "120" [117]=> string(4) "mffl" [118]=> string(6) "855.00" [119]=> string(6) "-43.33" [120]=> string(3) "300" [121]=> string(4) "siem" [122]=> string(8) "1,331.00" [123]=> string(6) "-38.00" [124]=> string(3) "600" [125]=> string(4) "pakt" [126]=> string(6) "620.00" [127]=> string(6) "-27.90" [128]=> string(5) "1,000" [129]=> string(3) "sfl" [130]=> string(6) "409.00" [131]=> string(6) "-15.90" [132]=> string(5) "9,400" [133]=> string(4) "gadt" [134]=> string(6) "286.00" [135]=> string(6) "-13.37" [136]=> string(6) "48,800" [137]=> string(4) "atba" [138]=> string(6) "394.79" [139]=> string(6) "-12.96" [140]=> string(3) "900" [141]=> string(3) "btl" [142]=> string(6) "265.51" [143]=> string(5) "-8.49" [144]=> string(5) "1,200" [145]=> string(4) "natf" [146]=> string(6) "616.00" [147]=> string(5) "-8.26" [148]=> string(5) "1,200" [149]=> string(4) "admm" [150]=> string(6) "121.51" [151]=> string(5) "-6.39" [152]=> string(6) "98,500" }
```

And i want to find  "kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30"  which is located at key number 23
I have tried in_array and other php array functions including preg_match but it dont find string in array. Is there a way to find string in my array. If yes then tell me

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

So it must be like ..

```
echo $key = array_search('kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30', $yourarray); //"prints" 23
```

**`EDIT:`**

```
<?php
$array = [
    0 => "colg - colgate palmolive (pakistan) ltd. ",
    1 => "gatm - gul ahmed textile mills ltd. ",
    2 => "atlh - atlas honda limited ",
    3 => "ffbl - fauji fertilizer bin qasim",
    4 => " - general news",
    5 => "searl - the searl company ltd. ",
    23 => " kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30 ",
    24 => "26,730.82",
];

$array = array_map('trim',$array);

$searchText = 'kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30';
$searchText = trim($searchText);
echo $key = array_search($searchText, $array); //"prints" 23
```

[<kbd>`Demo`</kbd>](https://eval.in/95618)

Comment: `i already tried from google and php.net ` You serious ? Then post those efforts in the question and not pledging here for answers.

Comment: Just tell me the way to search that string in array, i tried functions you are telling but they are not working on this array but works on other. Copy the array and try it yourself you will see, that is why i give the array to tell my problem

Comment: Can't you read my comment ? **Post your efforts on your question.** You know how to edit a question right ?

Answer (score 0):

Well your "kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30" has a space " " before and after the string in your array.

```
string(136) " kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30 "
```

Is this the reason why you cannot find it? Because array_serach, in_array and other functions are looking for exact values.

Otherwise use strstr to compare if your string is inside your haystack but be careful. If you have similar content like "Hello" and "Hello World" in your array you might find the wrong entry to this is not really a good unique solution.

Anyway I am leaving a quick example:

```
$found = false;
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if(strstr($value, "kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30") == true) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($found == true) {
    //Do something awesome!
} else {
    //Do something not so awesome but still cool?
}
```

Comment: I doubt that because this is definetly correct, depending on your array maybe you got a typing error in your comparisation string

Comment: @BurhanAhmed, If you can't be patient. Get help elsewhere. Get a freelancer to do this job. I am flagging your comment.

Comment: You should rather post your code to proof that you did no misstake. I doubt that my answer is wrong im not doing this for the first time you know?

Comment: Bro, you are telling correct, my code is working on every array and on this array to, i am getting the value from this array like array[23] but when i search array to find that string it wont work

Comment: Because again FFS value with index #23 has a space in the beginning and end of its value " kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30 " instead of expected: " "kse 100 kse 30 kmi 30" and if you compare strings they must be identical, not almost identical! "test" != " test "...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For you help but i sort it out myself

```
for ($index = 10; $index < 35; $index++) {
    if (substr_count(array[$index], 'kse 100') > 0) {
      $IndexKey = $index;
    }     
}
```

Got The value of key where that variable is.

Comment: `parse error` and no need to use `substr_count()` and use `break` so as not to loop the entire array.  Also, only works for indexes 10 to 35.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one that matches:

```
$key = key(preg_grep('/kse 100/', $array));
```